# Excel: Empilhar todas as colunas em uma única coluna

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma planilha onde a mesma possui 2412 colunas com 20 linhas preenchidas cada uma. O que gostaria de fazer é mover todas essas 2412 colunas com seus respectivos registros em uma única coluna. Cheguei a tentar a opção **Tranpor**, a função **=VSTACK** e no Power Query as opções **transformar colunas** para tentar empilhar todas as colunas que possuo em uma única lista/coluna porém sem sucesso.

Abaixo segue um esboço/exemplo da planilha na ordem que está:

```
coluna 1 | coluna 2 | coluna 3
-------------------------------
01       | 06       | 11
02       | 07       | 12
03       | 08       | 13
04       | 09       | 14
05       | 10       | 15
```

Abaixo, a forma como gostaria que estivesse:

```
coluna 1
---------
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

Como forma de demonstrar o problema, segue um link de uma planilha excel:

[Planilha - Transformar colunas em uma única lista/coluna](https://file.io/R8aOHAzbTt6n)

Answer (score -2):

Irei postar a solução que encontrei para o problema relatado aqui.

- Primeiro, selecionei a área onde encontram-se os dados das colunas.
- Feito isso, cliquei no menu "Dados" e em seguida fui em "Obter e Transformar Dados" clicando na opção "De Tabela / Intervalo".
- Após ter clicado na opção "De Tabela / Intervalo", aparecerá uma caixa de diálogo. Clique no botão "ok". Feito isso, o editor Power Query será aberto.
- Já no editor Power Query, vá até o menu "Adicionar Coluna" e clique em "Coluna de índice" na setinha com sentido pra baixo e em seguida clique na opção "De 0". Após isso, será criada uma coluna chamada "índice".
- Clique com o botão direito no cabeçalho dessa coluna "índice" e escolha a opção "Transformar Outras Colunas em Linha".
- Após isso, uma nova tabela com os dados empilhados aparecerão. Caso os dados estejam empilhados corretamente, é só ir no menu "Arquivo" e clicar na opção "Fechar e Carregar" e todos os dados aparecerão empilhados e ordenados.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

Para juntar todas as colunas em uma única coluna, uma opção é usar a função "Consolidar" do Excel. Aqui estão os passos para fazer isso:

Selecione a célula onde você deseja colocar os dados consolidados.
Na guia "Dados", clique em "Consolidar" na seção "Dados de Análise".
Na caixa de diálogo "Consolidar", selecione a opção "Por posição de células" e clique em "OK".
Na caixa de diálogo "Referências", adicione todas as colunas que você deseja consolidar na seção "Referências". Você pode fazer isso clicando na seta para baixo ao lado da caixa de texto e selecionando cada coluna na planilha.
Clique em "OK" para fechar a caixa de diálogo "Referências" e a função "Consolidar" irá juntar todas as colunas em uma única coluna na célula selecionada